# PHP detect Internet Explorer (Edge) 15 and below, flag non CSS Grid support

Tags: php, regex, internet-explorer, user-agent

I am looking to create a php function that detects Internet Explorer 15 and below. The reason for this is due to their lack of support for [CSS Grid](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid). I'd like to be able to use php to add additional code regarding the browser support.

I've found several libraries that do very robust detection, however for my case that is too much overhead and I believe this should be a simple check of the user agent. Just not sure if there was already a solution out there. I have done some looking and have not found anything specifically for this.

This solution seems to find anything IE 11 and below

```
<?php
if (preg_match('~MSIE|Internet Explorer~i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) || (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Trident/7.0; rv:11.0') !== false)) {
echo 'ie11';
}
?>
```

Here is another idea, not sure if this works for edge?

```
<?php
$userAgent = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']); 
if (preg_match('/msie/', $userAgent)) { 
    $name = 'ie'; 
} elseif (preg_match('/trident/', $userAgent)) { 
    $name = 'ie'; 
} else { 
    $name = 'unrecognized'; 
} 
if(preg_match('/.+(?:rv|it|ra|ie)[\/: ]([\d.]+)/', $userAgent, $matches)) { 
    $version = $matches[1]; 
} else { 
    $version = 'unknown'; 
} 
if($name == 'ie' && $version < '15'){
    print 'You are using an unsupported browser';
}
?>
```

Comment: Internet Explorer 11 was the last release of IE. Are you intending to check versions 12 - 15 against Microsoft Edge?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: https://codepen.io/kamakalolii/pen/MpraLZ Why not use JS ?

Comment: `$ua = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']); // Check for Edge, then old version below 16 and add in -ms-grid display
preg_match('/edge\/([\d.]+)/i', $ua, $matches);

if ($matches[1]) {
  $versionNumber = intval($matches[1]);
  if ($versionNumber < 16) {
    echo 'something';
  }
}`